# SD card need to be ejected and pushed back in order to boot

Tags: sd-card, pi-2

I have had come across many cases where I boot a RPi-b+ or RPi-2 and the next time I try to use it it doesn't boot. It appears that if I eject the SD card and push it back in, it boots fine.

And this is without moving the RPi around too much. I don't know if the SD card is that sensitive that it doesn't take much to lose connectivity.

I didn't have similar problems with the RPi-b.

Does anyone has similar problems?

Any suggestions on how to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you shut Pi down?

Comment: Search for loose SD card.

Comment: In most cases the Pi shuts down by removing the power.

Comment: Have you tried a second SD card to see if the problem continues with it installed?

Comment: Are you doing this instead of unplugging the power from the Pi?

Comment: @CalvinMcGill: the problem appears appears randomly. If I eject and reinsert event the same card the Pi works fine.

Comment: @SteveRobillard: nope.